# Third largest area without sorting

Tags: c++, arrays

I am taking an introductory class to programming and am trying to find the third largest area in an array of circles and then return the index of where this circle can be found without sorting, but ran into some troubles.

Input

```
Circle [0] 157/50
Circle [1] 314/25
Circle [2] 1413/50 
Circle [3] 1256/25 
Circle [4] 152/7
```

Expected Output

```
2
```

Actual Output

```
4
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think I assigned the wrong values to `largest`, `secondlargest`, and `thirdlargest`? Why is it returning `4`? Here's what I have so far, thank you for the help. ^_^

```
int getThirdLargestArea(Circle** arr, int size) {
    Circle largest = *arr[0];
    Circle secondlargest = *arr[size - 1];
    Circle thirdlargest = secondlargest;

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (largest.getArea() > arr[i]->getArea()) {
            thirdlargest = secondlargest;
            secondlargest = largest;
            largest = *arr[i];
            index = i;
        }

        else if (secondlargest.getArea() > arr[i]->getArea()) {
            thirdlargest = secondlargest;
            secondlargest = *arr[i];
            index = i;

        }

        else if (thirdlargest.getArea() > arr[i]->getArea()) {
            thirdlargest = *arr[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: look at each of your if statements. for example: `largest.getArea() > arr[i]->getArea()`. Do you really want to be doing what you are doing in the block if the largest area is greater or smaller?

Comment: *whipsers* no you dont. just change your conditionals. also, I suggest initializing the `secondlargest` and `thirdlargest` circles as either circles with no area or equal the same as the largest rather than the last circle, who knows, what if the last circle is bigger than the first

Comment: Why not make use of actual c++ and do [`minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax)? Or [`nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

Comment: I just have to say - great question structure, especially given that it's homework-related. Thanks for not posting a "giv me da codez!!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These initializations are incorrect:

```
Circle largest = *arr[0];
Circle secondlargest = *arr[size - 1];
Circle thirdlargest = secondlargest;
```

They assume a few generally incorrect conditions: that the first element is larger than the last (true in your test case, false in general), and that there is an additional element equal to the last element (very unreasonable).

You should initialize your `largest`, `secondlargest` and `thirdlargest` to the first 3 elements, properly sorted:

```
largest_idx = 0;
secondlargest_idx = 1;
thirdlargest_idx = 2;

// bubble-sort of an array of 3 elements:
// swap 0 <-> 1 if needed
// swap 1 <-> 2 if needed
// swap 0 <-> 1 if needed
if (arr[largest_idx]->getArea() < arr[secondlargest_idx]->getArea())
    std::swap(largest_idx, secondlargest_idx);
if (arr[secondlargest_idx]->getArea() < arr[thirdlargest_idx]->getArea())
    std::swap(secondlargest_idx, thirdlargest_idx);
if (arr[largest_idx]->getArea() < arr[secondlargest_idx]->getArea())
    std::swap(largest_idx, secondlargest_idx);
```

Here I am using indices instead of objects because your function has to calculate an index, not return the object.

Then start examining the elements from the fourth one (the first one that was not examined yet):

```
for (int i = 3; i < size; i++) {
    ...
}
```

It's incorrect to examine an object twice, because e.g. the second largest element, repeated twice, can make you forget the third largest element.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should replace > with < in three places in your code. For example, here: `if (largest.getArea() > arr[i]->getArea())` you should enter `if` block if the ith element has greater area than your current largest area. Moreover, you should remember the first, second and third circles indices instead of circles themselves. You always update `index` with value of `i` but it is only correct in the last `else` block. If you remembered indices instead of circles, you would return `thirdLargestIdx` instead.

You should also be careful with your initial values of largest, secondlargest and thirdlargest variables. You shouldn't assume any particular order of sizes of circles you chose.

Just for completness, there is O(n) algorithm for finding kth largest element in array: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Comment: For tiny K that O(n) algorithm is far slower than the simple way.  3 is a very tiny choice for K.  Done correctly the simple way is `n log K`. When K is part of the problem definition, rather than one of the inputs, that is O(n).

Comment: I agree that in this case "median of medians" algorithm is not the best choice. I just mentioned it to show that there is a more general method for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please prefer standard containers over legacy C-arrays and pointer arithmetics. Also try to use standard algorithms where reasonable.

```
auto getThirdLargestArea(const std::vector<Circle>& circles) -> int {
  // this will hold the three largest circles known
  auto largest = std::vector<std::pair<int, const Circle*>>{};

  // iterate over all circles
  for(size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); ++i) {
    // add the current index and circle to the largest list
    largest.insert(std::find_if(std::begin(largest), std::end(largest),
                                [&](const std::pair<int, const Circle*>& c) {
                                  return c.second->getArea() < circles[i].getArea();
                                },
                   std::pair<int, const Circle*>{i, &(circles[i])});
    // we are only interested in the three largest, so drop the rest.
    largest.resize(std::min(largest.size(), 3));
  }

  if(largest.size() < 3)
    // there were less than 3 circles -> signal an error
    return -1;

  // now we can simply read the third largest from your vector
  return largest[2].first;
}
```

I use pointers to prevent copying of the circles. Since `largest` never owns the circles, there is no leak anywhere in this code. Since the pointers in `largest` always point into the const vector `circles`, the pointers can't dangle around anywhere.

Note: the code in this answer requires C++11 features and is untested. therefore it will likely contain some bugs.